# Relaxed Adaptive Lasso

Tags: lasso, glmnet

I recently came across [this study](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/14/7/1422) describing the benefits of the author's relaxed adaptive LASSO regression. The author describes a simple algorithm (which appears to be glmnet, effectively), as well as a newer algorithm which is slightly optimized for speed. It occurs to me that you could possibly do something similar in glmnet like this:

```
# Given some X.train and y.train

  # Generate Penalties
  set.seed(999)
  cv.ridge <- cv.glmnet(X.train, 
                        y.train, 
                        type.measure = "mae", 
                        alpha = 0, # This ensures ridgeiness
                        #parallel = T,
                        standardize = T)
  penalty <- 1/abs(as.numeric(coef(cv.ridge, s = cv.ridge$lambda.min))[-1])
  
  # Adaptive LASSO Regression w/ Ridge Weights
  
  model.meta <- cv.glmnet(X.train,
                          y.train, 
                          type.measure = "mae",
                          alpha = 1, # This ensures lassoiness
                          #parallel = T,
                          standardize = T,
                          penalty.factor = penalty,
                          nfolds = 3,
                          relax = T
                          )
```

However, I just want to verify that this is legit since I can't find any other examples of a relaxed adaptive lasso. Is anyone aware of any issue with using this configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how you've incorporated the "relaxed" part: this looks like a standard adaptive lasso to me. But that being said, combining the relaxed and adaptive lassos, as the article you linked advocates, doesn't make any sense to begin with, so I would say you're good to go.

Comment: @JohnMadden would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Sorry to reply to a question with another question: I see that you have used the penalty.factor parameter set to the inverse of an initial estimate of the coefficient magnitudes to implement the adaptive lasso. Which part of this script implements the relaxation?

Comment: No worries. The relax = T argument implements relaxation internally. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/relax.pdf for more details.

Comment: Oh I missed that. I would say that you have correctly implemented the algo the authors describe in section 2.2 (of course substituting ridge for OLS in the pre-estimation stage).